# Can you see if someone writes a comment or answer at this moment?

Tags: feature-request

Can you see if someone writes at this moment a comment or answer?

When I write a comment I will able see if another user is writing as well.

It will help me.

Comment: Nope, you can't and this has been requested before

Comment: Why can't I? What the problem?

Comment: I meant you can't see if someone is writing either an answer or comment and this feature request has been asked before and I believe was status-declined.

Comment: OK rope:( Rather it seems to me a good idea :)

Answer (score 0):

You say it would help you, but you don't explain how.

Realtime notifying N users about actions of M users would take extra computational and network resources and give almost nothing. I doubt that it would ever be implemented without some good reason.

If you have something to say worth a comment, then post it.

If you know the answer, post an answer. As for other users - there are plenty of them. Just assume that  someone will post an answer sometime if you don't.

If you want to be notified about answers to your question, just setup the email notifications. Mobile application is also a great way to get notified.

If you want to track answers to a question of another user, there's a subscription link under each question.

Comment: This will save time so I can know if someone wanted to respond to any time soon.

Comment: @Eliyahu-Shmuel still not clear. If you knew that someone is going to post a comment, what would or wouldn't you do?

Comment: Wait for answer and not close my computer:)

Comment: @Eliyahu-Shmuel please read the edit.

Comment: Even with the good functional reason I'd still wager that the amount of additional traffic this will generate is still a better technical reason not to do it :)